# Avoid declaring "_8" for fortran real variables?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, precision

I assigned a real variable in Fortran code as `a=0.00001`. On printing the variable on following line gave `a=9.9999997473787516E-006` instead of `1E-5`.

The fix for this problem is declaring `a=0.00001_8` or `a=0.00001_rk` with `rk` defined with value `8`.

I want to avoid this `underscore` style in my programming. Is there a way to do this without underscores as is in `C` or `C++`

Comment: There are ways to use `0.00001` giving something like `0.0001_rk`, but to really answer the question it would be useful to understand _why_ you want to avoid using the (entirely appropriate) form `0.0001_rk`.  I could avoid writing `0` in my program by writing `1-1` instead, but I doubt anyone would suggest doing that.

Comment: Basically for better readability, I do not want to have any suffixes. Sometimes the length of the code simply increases due to suffixes at multiple places. Is there a way to do this as in C or C++, where we dont use any suffixes for declared variables?

Comment: You should strive to have your code be maintainable and portable. Avoiding the `_rk` notation is neither of those things. Readability is important, but secondary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll list a couple options here, but ultimately the answer is **use the underscore notation**. Especially when developing new code, all real variables should use a `kind` parameter. There are several good many ways to define a kind parameter:

- `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` has reals and integers defined by their size: `REAL32`, `REAL64`, `INT32`, `INT64`, and others.
- Use the intrinsic function `SELECTED_REAL_KIND` to obtain a kind with the specified precision and exponent range
- `IEEE_SELECTED_REAL_KIND` for IEEE compatability
- `ISO_C_BINDING` contains `C_DOUBLE` and others for C interoperability

This way, you can achieve the desired precision on any machine. For example,

```
use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only : wp => REAL64
real(wp) :: x
```

The important part is to have `wp` be explicitly declared. Then, if you want x to have the value 0.1, you set it equal to 0.1 represented using the `wp` kind using

```
x = 0.1_wp
```

This is the fortran notation. You should not reject it simply because you think it's less readable.

---

However, I will include a couple other options. They're not as good though!

- Declare constants using `d` instead of `e`, which requests `double precision`, for example `x = 0.1d0`
- Use a compiler flag to change the default real kind. In `gfortran`, you would typically use `-fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8`. This compiler option doesn't always exist (certainly not in the exact same way), and also limits the possible real kinds you can declare.

Comment: As well as c_double from iso_c_binding

Comment: I've add your suggestions to the body, thanks @francescalus and tim

Answer (score 0):

You may use the exponent D instead of E :

```
a=0.00001d0
```

which is only useful if your variable a has been declared either double precision of real(rk) wih rk defined as :

```
integer,parameter :: rk=selected_real_kind(15,100)
```

In addition, don't use `_8` but `_rk` (`_8` is not portable).

Comment: This is true if the kind value `rk` (or `8`) is the same as that of double precision.

Comment: @francescalus which is almost always the case... except when I was using Cray or CDC computers a long time ago !

Comment: I used a compiler just an hour ago which would refuse to accept `1._8`.  And that same compiler, if I asked it, could also accept that `rk` as being the default kind.

Comment: @FrancoisJacq I guess you misunderstood the question. I do not want to have any suffixes. How to do this?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan you cannot : 0.0001 is a single precision number in Fortran and a double precision number in C.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan In fact, it often exists a compiler dependent option promoting single precison to double precision automatically. But this is not "standard"

Comment: @SathishKrishnan with the compiler gfortran, the right compiling option is -freal-4-real-8

Comment: @FrancoisJacq Be careful, there are several promoting flags for gfortran and they differ somewhat. The option you propose will also promote variables explicitly declared kind and the manual warns that care should be taken.

Comment: @VladimirF you are surely right : I never use this kind of option and it was difficult to find the right option in the jungle of gfortran options ;-)