# Is Fortran's DBLE intrinsic function obsolete?

Tags: fortran

In the Fortran standard, `dble` is an intrinsic function in the same way as `real`. The recommended way of working with double precision numbers is to use `iso_fortran_env`. Thus, we have two ways of converting to double

```
program demo
 use iso_fortran_env, only : REAL64, INT32
 integer(INT32) :: i
 real(REAL64)   :: x, y
 i = 5
 x = dble(i)
 y = real(i, REAL64)
end program demo
```

But is there a difference between `dble(...)` and `real(...,REAL64)`? Are there usage cases where one form should be preferred over the other?

Isn't it that the very existence of `iso_fortran_env` makes `dble` obsolete? Or conversely, if every compiler is supposed to know what double type is why do we need `iso_fortran_env` (it might be very useful for other purposes though)?

Comment: `real(real64)` isn't the same thing as `double precision`.

Comment: @francescalus According to the book "Modern fortran explained" by M. Metcalf `double precision` is a deprecated feature (Sec. A.6). That is why my confusion and that is why I am asking this question on the first place. Do we expect `dble` to disappear anytime soon? If not, why?

Comment: I think you should ask more clearly if it is ok to use `dble()` now and in the future since all this talk about obsolescence confuses things.

Comment: Metcalf et al is only expressing an opinion.  `double precision` is not listed among the Obsolescent features of the language.  The correct way to cause conversion is to let the compiler do its job: `x = i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dble` is obsolete in some sense,<sup>1</sup> but this obsolescence is entirely unrelated to the existence of `real64` from `iso_fortran_env`.

The following are equivalent:

```
double precision x
x = dble(1)
end
```

and

```
real(kind(0d0)) y
y = real(1, kind(0d0))
end
```

Indeed, the result of `dble` in the first is defined precisely as that of `real` in the second.

The following are *not* equivalent:

```
double precision x
x = dble(1)
end
```

and

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real64
real(real64) y
y = real(1, real64)
end
```

`x` and `y` may have the same kind, but they may also be different: `real64` is not guaranteed to be a valid kind number (a processor may not have a 64-bit storage real); even if `double precision` is a 64-bit real, that doesn't mean `real64` is that kind (there could be two more more 64-bit reals).

This is all to say, whatever one thinks about `double precision` as a type declaration, it's entirely wrong to think of replacing it with `real(real64)` instead of `real(rk)` where `rk` is the equivalent kind number for the processor's double precision.

"Double precision" in Fortran doesn't mean the same thing as "double precision" in IEEE floating point, but they may happen to match up. `real(real64)` means neither Fortran's "double precision" nor IEEE's "double precision" but may match one or the other or both.

---

Some historical context, to place the comment discussion: back in Fortran 77 (and before) the "double precision" was a completely different type from the "real". In Fortran 77 `real(y)` returns a real and `dble(y)` returns a double precision.

Only in Fortran 90 were the two unified to being kinds of the same type. We had `dble()` and `double precision` back then because of these differing types. Even though now we can use `real(kind=kind(0d0)) x` and `real(y, kind=kind(0d0)` we retain the history of the other ways, in a manner which is backward compatible. No deletion of the "obsolete" forms, which will break decades' code, is going to happen.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is certainly not defined as "obsolete" by the Fortran standard.

Comment: Yes, I agree. You formulated everything very carefully. I read several messages from it. 1) `double precision` must be replaced with more explicit type for some reasons (obsolesce).   2) You named this type `rk` but we even do not know how to put it in correspondence with iso-types. The only thing what is given by the standard is that the precision of double >= default real, which is very vague. Now I am puzzled. Many BLAS functions accept double precision type that soon will vanish and I do not even know how to convert to it because `dble` will probably vanish soon.

Comment: `double precision` (and hence `dble`) is not going anywhere any time soon. It's not even marked as obsolete in F2018 (or F2023) and that's a necessary first step. Even once officially obsolete, it won't be deleted until at least the next revision of the standard. Many  I'm not aware of any serious discussion about removing them. To be deleted an obsolescent feature must be "largely unused". As long as BLAS has "double precision" that requirement can never be met.

Comment: For your second point, portability of a Fortran program is widely misunderstood. If you develop a ternary computer with a novel floating point system and 27-bit bytes you can still provide a Fortran compiler, and your customers can expect to have their programs run. Neither you nor they can expect to get the same results for all programs as you'd be used to. (Neither should you expect the same results for the same program on two different existing computers.)

Comment: Right, your answer is very useful. Especially your comments on the persistence of double precision, importance of compatibility with BLAS and non-uniqueness of double precision itself. However, your point of view comes in tension with many other posts here, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796739/4954079.  "Especially when developing new code, all real variables should use a kind parameter." I do not see this necessity, do you?

Comment: @yarchik The authors Metcalf, Reid, Cohen just do not like `double precision` and call for using something else instead. Already in the F2003 version of the book. But they are careful in what they actually call obsolescent in the standard sense. Certainly not `double precision`. Similarly, they do not like `do while` even though it is not that old, just not necessary. It is a style suggestion.

Comment: @yarchik *"Especially when developing new code, all real variables should use a kind parameter."* This is also a style suggestion. This does not say that `double precision` is declared obsolescent in the standard. Good style in programming is very important. For Fortran there is a whole book about it https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6320571

Comment: @yarchik, I don't see a tension. I personally avoid `double precision` even using the arguably silly `real(kind(0d0))` instead of a `integer, parameter :: rk=...; real(rk)`. But I think the important part is, beyond style, always choose the kind of a real based on the characteristics you need: be that storage size, precision, radix, interop. If you aren't fussy, default real can be just as valid.#

Comment: Worth noting that while the Fortran language standard might delete a feature the compiler producers rarely do, any such deletions would break a lot of old codes. Fortran compilers either compile deleted features without complaint or offer a flag or two to persuade them to not complain. Of course, I'm writing about deleted standard features, not some of the wierd and wonderful extensions that various compilers have offered over the years.

Comment: @francescalus: better?

Comment: A terribly exciting question (for someone like me, rather than someone who just wants to get results for science), is what would happen if `double precision` were deleted. Would we be able to then call a derived type `doubleprecision` or would that still be prohibited? How horribly confusing would a compiler's logic get it if continued to accept `double precision x` to support old code while having to decide whether `type(doubleprecision) y` was an intrinsic or derived type? Fascinating, isn't it @HighPerformanceMark?

Comment: It's not just the old code that would break if some features from the 60s and 70s were deleted, there are a lot of us old Fortran programmers hanging around still who'd probably fly off the handle and start coding in APL.  (again)

Comment: `double precision` is still quite useful when writing libraries.

Comment: @PierU Semantically yes. Syntactically, it can be completely replaced by selecting the right kind constant `dp = kind(1.d0)`. That is what the Metcalf, Reid, Cohen objection is about.