# Confusing type checking report by NAG Fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran, nag-fortran

Consider the following Fortran code:

```
program kinds_demo
  use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL64, INT32
  integer(int32), parameter :: n=10
  real(real64)    :: A(n, n)
  complex(real64) :: B(n, n)
  real(real64)    :: tr, u(n*n), v(n*n)

  a=1.0D0
  b=1.0D0
  
  call dcopy(n*n, a, 1, u, 1)
  call dcopy(n*n, b, 2, v, 1)
  
  tr=dot_product(u,v)

  print*,tr
  
end program kinds_demo
```

I compile it with newest NAG Fortran compiler (NAG Fortran Compiler Release 7.1(Hanzomon) Build 7114)

```
nagfor -c -o kinds_demo.x kinds_demo.f90
```

and get this error message

> Error: kinds_demo.f90, line 12: Inconsistent data type
> COMPLEX(KIND(0d0)) (previously DOUBLE PRECISION) for argument 2 in
> reference to DCOPY

This is an *expected error* that only becomes evident by comparing the two `dcopy` calls. Upon commenting line 11 (first call) the program becomes valid as expected. Notice, I am not linking here. Therefore, the actual type of arguments is irrelevant here, only their consistency matters. But I do not understand the error message. Shouldn't it be written as

> Error: kinds_demo.f90, line 12: Inconsistent data type COMPLEX(2)
> (previously REAL(2)) for argument 2 in reference to DCOPY

Notice that `REAL64=2` for the NAG compiler.

It is [emphasized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75888074/4954079) many times here that `double precision` is not `REAL64`, but somehow NAG compiler (which is known for additional error checking and tools capabilities) assumes just opposite?

Comment: A thought experiment: if the kind number for default real is `6`, and you wrote `real(kind=1+2*3-5**0) y` would you want your compiler to complain about a mismatch with `real(6)` or `real(1+2*3-5**0)`?

Comment: @francescalus This is not a mismatch between a default and not default as in your example. This is a mismatch between two different types, in which a third (completely irrelevant in this context) type is mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but the message mentions some specific kind. gfortran or Intel would mention "real(4)" or "real(8)" no matter what exact expression you had in your code that contained the number 8 (e.g. `real64` or `rp` or `dp` or some other constant).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава In my opinion gfortran gives a completely valid and useful report "Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8))", I do not have ifort. But NAG identifies REAL64 with double precision, which is wrong. I agree with you that REAL64 is just a constant. But it can be reported as it is (it is equal to 2 for nagfor), and not distorted.

Comment: Actually, Intel (ifort and the newer ifx) compile that code without demur (but they have no hope of linking it). You haven't told the compiler that it might be an overloaded function with any sort of interface, so the compiler will have to assume that it is a single function and at least one of the function calls is wrong.

Comment: Looking again at the question, I do not get it: the error is from **line 12**, but you say that it goes away if you comment out the **line 11**. To me the error message you are reporting is not about a kind issue, but about a type issue: dcopy is expecting a `real` array and you try passing a `complex` array.

Comment: @PierU, you misunderstand the root cause, perhaps. Commenting out any one call to `dcopy` makes the code valid. It's having two calls to the same procedure using different argument types that is wrong. Commenting out line 11 means the call on line 12 is the only call to `dcopy`, so no error. Commenting out line 12 means the call on line 11 is the only call to `dcopy`: no error. (`dcopy` is an external procedure with implicit interface: the compiler has no idea/care what the correct argument type should be.)

Comment: @francescalus my bad! I didn't get that, as ifort (the compiler I am using on a regular basis) doesn't perform this kind of check by default. Instead, I thought that NAG was somehow providing explicit interfaces to the blas routines.

Answer (score 0):

Kind parameters are numbers. Consider:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real32  ! Value 1
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_float   ! Value 1

implicit none

real(kind=1) a
real(kind=5**0) b
real(kind=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(radix=6)) c          ! Kind value 1
real(kind=real32) d
real(kind=c_float) e
real f                                            ! Default real has kind 1

end
```

where all those expressions for the kind evaluate to `1`. Each of those variables are the same type and kind (default real, kind `1`).

When a compiler sees a constant expression where a kind parameter is required, it evaluates the expression and uses the value. While a compiler *can* store the actual constant name/expression used in declaring an object to enhance later error message reporting, this is not common.

Many compilers will complain, not as NAG has chosen with an explanation, simply with the numeric value:

```
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).
```

The NAG compiler is choosing to take a value and express it in a more descriptive way with the mapping (using the default 1,2,3 numbering scheme):

- kind value 1 -> "real" / "complex"
- kind value 2 -> "double precision" / "complex(kind(0d0)"
- kind value 3 -> "real(real128)" / "complex(real128)

(for the "odd" kind 2, note that "double complex" is a non-standard extension offered by compilers other than NAG's and "complex(double precision)" wouldn't work)

Now, we've stressed previously that "double precision" is not "real(128)". By this, we don't mean `kind(0d0)/=real128`, but that the two values aren't necessarily the same. They may be the same.

The mapping is intended to be more helpful than a naked number, rather than perfectly expressing the code that was seen (at a different compilation stage). Usually, that's all that's required. Recall that NAG supports different numbering schemes for kinds (`-kind=sequential`, `-kind=byte` and `-kind=unique`): using the numeric values can cause other confusion.

As usual, if you think a compiler's error message could be improved, please do contact the compiler vendor with your suggestion. If the developers agree and see it as worthwhile, perhaps with dozens of other requests, the error message and diagnostics may be changed to what you'd prefer.

Comment: I know that `REAL64` is an integer number. But this is not the point of the original post, which I edited slightly to accommodate this point. The question was why real or complex number of certain kind is referenced by the reputed compiler as double precision. No reason whatsoever.

Comment: "Recall that NAG supports different numbering schemes for kinds (`-kind=sequential`, `-kind=byte` and `-kind=unique`): using the numeric values can cause other confusion." NAG evidently have decided that it is more desirable to report using consistent descriptions of the kind parameters instead of actual values (which could be `2`, `8`, or `302` in current builds). Did I know that `double precision` has kind value `302`? No, I looked it up. I didn't need to look up "double precision" or "kind(0d0)".

Comment: @yarchik No reason whatsoever, but why not? The compiler sees the kind=2, knows that it corresponds to `double precision` and hence refers to `double precision` in the error message. This is maybe not the way you would like, but this is technically correct.

Comment: @PierU That is the point, it is not technically correct. In the linked post francescalus  wrote  "whatever one thinks about double precision as a type declaration, it's entirely wrong to think of replacing it with real(real64)". And I have no reasons to believe that the reverse argument is not valid. If we read the previous comment of francescalus, nag sees 2 and reports 302, funny...

Comment: @yarchik It **is** technically correct. In the context of the NAG compiler on the platform you are using, a `real(real64)` is semantically identical to a `double precision`, which doesn't meant it is in other contexts. By the way, the `dcopy()` routine is written with dummy arguments declared as `double precision`: yet, the NAG compiler doesn't complain at all if the actual arguments are declared as `real(real64))`

Comment: @yarchik, the main thrust of my defence of NAG: if I pass a double precision to a real argument (another form of mismatch) I find the error message "expected 'real', got 'double precision'" to be lot quicker to process than "expected 'real(301), got 'real(302)'", especially when another time I compile the same code could give the error "expected 'real(1)', got 'real(2)'" or "expected 'real(4)', got 'real(8)'". When I fail like that I'm usually using default real/double precision instead of real32/64 and there is a trade-off for confusion in those cases, but worrying about 302 vs 2...?

Comment: It seems you have a strong opinion about this. You should report to the developers of gfortran. They choose a different approach, which, in all honesty, I would also follow. But this becomes a dispute about tastes and not facts :)

Comment: @yarchik, the difference with gfortran is that there only one kind numbering scheme is supported. default real in gfortran is always kind 4, `double precision` in gfortran is always kind 8. nagfor has a real strength in allowing `-kind=unique` where the kind numbers are effectively (for the compiler user) "random". With nagfor a consistent "human readable" name is important (as you say, to my taste - I appreciate this won't be the case for everyone, so if you feel the numeric value is better, that's a good suggestion to make to NAG).

Comment: Thank you! I am not accepting your answer at the moment because I still hope that developers of nag fortran read this forum and can maybe provide their vision.